# What does "Total Received" represent in Resources in the system monitor?

Tags: system-monitor, 21.10

In the Resources tab in the stock system monitor on 21.10 there's a Total Received field under the network graph. In the same session it has shown e.g. 200 KiB, 2 MiB, 180 KiB, 3 MiB, 30 MiB, 900 KiB, in that order.

At first I thought it was showing what it says: the total (since logging in), but when it proved to not be cumulative I now have no clue what it represents.

What is this field telling me?